# SQLite database update doesn't update

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio

I am trying to write to SQL database on android. It works fine to create items in the database but I can't seem to be able to go back and edit them. To prove I have already hard coded an existing item ID and tried to update it but it still doesn't work, so that means there is likely something wrong with my code, or I am using it wrong. Tell me if I am missing something. This is the code that is supposed to update the database. By default, COLUMN_STATE gets a "2" and I am replacing it with a "3" here. But it just stays at 2 after this runs.

```
    public long markMessageRead(String messageId) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Messages.COLUMN_STATE, "3");

    // updating row
    return db.update(Messages.TABLE_NAME, values, Messages.COLUMN_MESSAGE_ID + " = ?",
            new String[]{String.valueOf(messageId)});
}
```

Comment: If your `messageId` method arg is a `String`, there's no need to take its `valueOf` later. But as long as `messageId` really has the value you think, it should still work. Also assuming your constants really do have the values they are supposed to, the whole method looks correct to me. That said, if this method is returning `0` and there is no error, then an incorrect `messageId` seems like the most likely culprit, since that's what would happen if there is simply no match for the `WHERE` clause. That could be human error, or a parsing/type conversion problem somewhere down the call stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change ContentValues!**

> values.put(<this is columns(field)'s name in your table>, "3"); by you
> description > < COLUMN_STATE gets a "2" > this maybe values in your
> table.

Example :

```
 ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
 values.put("number", "3");
 db.update(Messages.TABLE_NAME, values, Messages.COLUMN_MESSAGE_ID + " = ?",
 new String[]{String.valueOf(messageId)});
```

another way by update :

```
 String where = "id = 'your id'";
 db.update(table, values, where, null); //where can be null
```

It's work the same way, if this doesn't help you,Please try to test with rawQuery.